# Android TextView not getting set

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I am learning Android development now and I wanted to try out whatever basic programs I've done in iOS development. The problem is to get the weather condition of a place and set the condition in TextView.

**Code**

```
package com.bh.weather;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            String value = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data")
                    .getJSONArray("current_condition").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("weatherDesc").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("value");
            Log.d("bh", value);
            MainActivity m = new MainActivity();
            m.setTextView(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urlTojson) {
        String json = new String();
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(urlTojson[0]);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            json = reader.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView tv = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //changed the API key here to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        new WeatherTask().execute("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Bangalore,India&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

    public void setTextView(String v) {
        Log.d("bh","Inside setTextView:"+v);
        if(v.equals("")) {
            Log.d("bh","Value not received");
        }
        else {
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            tv.setText(v);
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting JSON looks like this (jsonviewer.stack.hu can be used for viewing) :

```
{
  "data": {
    "current_condition": [
      {
        "cloudcover": "0",
        "humidity": "30",
        "observation_time": "01:29 PM",
        "precipMM": "0.0",
        "pressure": "1017",
        "temp_C": "25",
        "temp_F": "77",
        "visibility": "10",
        "weatherCode": "113",
        "weatherDesc": [
          {
            "value": "Clear"
          }
        ],
        "weatherIconUrl": [
          {
            "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png"
          }
        ],
        "winddir16Point": "E",
        "winddirDegree": "90",
        "windspeedKmph": "13",
        "windspeedMiles": "8"
      }
    ],
    "request": [
      {
        "query": "Bangalore, India",
        "type": "City"
      }
    ],
    "weather": [
      {
        "date": "2013-01-25",
        "precipMM": "0.0",
        "tempMaxC": "29",
        "tempMaxF": "84",
        "tempMinC": "15",
        "tempMinF": "59",
        "weatherCode": "113",
        "weatherDesc": [
          {
            "value": "Sunny"
          }
        ],
        "weatherIconUrl": [
          {
            "value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
          }
        ],
        "winddir16Point": "E",
        "winddirDegree": "97",
        "winddirection": "E",
        "windspeedKmph": "17",
        "windspeedMiles": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/place_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="@string/weather_condition" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:text="@string/show_weather" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see from the code, I get the value "Clear" after parsing (USES Internet permission set). But for some reason, this is not getting set in the TextView. I don't know what mistake I have done here. Logcat is showing the logged values properly. Please help.

Cheers.

Comment: You are creating a **new** instance of MainActivity and calling its `setTextView()`,and not dealing with the existing instance.

Comment: Oh, so how do I get the existing instance of MainActivity to set the Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    MainActivity mActivity;
     public WeatherTask(MainActivity mActivity){

          this.mActivity=mActivity;
                  }

protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        String value = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data")
                .getJSONArray("current_condition").getJSONObject(0)
                .getJSONArray("weatherDesc").getJSONObject(0)
                .getString("value");
        Log.d("bh", value);

        mActivity.setTextView(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urlTojson) {
    String json = new String();
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(urlTojson[0]);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        json = reader.readLine();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
}

 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private TextView tv = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//changed the API key here to xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    new WeatherTask(this).execute("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=Bangalore,India&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}

public void setTextView(String v) {
    Log.d("bh","Inside setTextView:"+v);
    if(v.equals("")) {
        Log.d("bh","Value not received");
    }
    else {
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv.setText(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you will need to pass activity Context using Constructor `AsyncTask` inside instead of Create it inside AsyncTask . change your code as :

```
class WeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
public Context context;
  public WeatherTask(Context context){

     this.context=context;
  }
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            String value = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data")
                    .getJSONArray("current_condition").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("weatherDesc").getJSONObject(0)
                    .getString("value");
            Log.d("bh", value);

            context.setTextView(value); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 //your code here....
```

and pass Activity context as from MainActivity :

```
    WeatherTask weatherobj=new WeatherTask(MainActivity.this);
        weatherobj.execute("http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/
weather.ashx?q=Bangalore,India&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```